# How to draw this parametic equation in java

Tags: java, graphics, equation

How to draw this parametic equation in java:

[image: The image of wanted result]

I have tried  this

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate(200, 200);
        int n = 1000;
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        double t = -300.0f;
        x1 = (int) (200 * Math.cos(0.56 * t)
                * Math.sin(0.56 * t)
                / (1 + Math.pow(2, Math.pow(Math.cos(2.02 * t), 2))));
        y1 = (int) (200 * Math.sin(0.56 * t) / 1 + Math.pow(Math.sin(2.02 * t), 2));
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            t = (double) 30 * i * Math.PI / n;
            x2 = (int) (200 * Math.cos(0.56 * t)
                    * Math.sin(0.56 * t)
                    / (1 + Math.pow(2, Math.pow(Math.cos(2.02 * t), 2))));
            y2 = (int) (200 * Math.sin(0.56 * t)
                    / 1 + (Math.pow(Math.sin(2.02 * t), 2)));
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
        }
    }
```

This is what I got:

[image: The result I got]

Comment: For a start, your initial value for `t` is -300 instead of -3

Comment: Did you miss parenthesis here `y1 = (int) (200 * Math.sin(0.56 * t) / 1 + Math.pow(Math.sin(2.02 * t), 2));` around `1 + Math.pow(Math.sin(2.02 * t), 2)`